# How to create an HD wallet transaction in ethereum? How to sign a transaction for multiple addresses in ethereum?

Tags: wallet-transfer

Suppose I know the number of hd child addresses used by my ethereum account, i want to send ether from those addresses.
How to sign such a transaction using ethereumjs-tx?

I need to send all the private keys and the from address should be an array too.